# How to forward and change the origin of a message via Dovecot Sieve script

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sieve

I want to forward an incoming mail to another recipient. However, the recipient is only accepting mails from my email address. Is it possible to forward a mail and change the sender via Sieve? The behavior should be similar to the behavior of a mail forward in a mail client like Thunderbird.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
require "editheader";

deleteheader "from";
addheader "From" "youremailadress@here.com";
redirect "toyourfriend@where.com";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: deleteheader does not work for me: Sieve parser error: line 12: unknown command deleteheader